# Multiple data sources per model

Tags: backbone.js

I have a collection that represents a list of movies that is loaded from a `url` with `.fetch()`. This url returns a list of movies the summary information, say `movieid` and `moviename`. I then want to load more information on this movie from another URL based on `movieid` inside this collection.

So my first url (http://movieapi.com/popular) responds with say:

```
{ 
    "movies": [ { "movieid": "1234", "moviename": "Iron Man" } ]
}
```

I then want to load for each model in the collection http://movieapi.com/movie/{movieid} which responds with say:

```
{
    "cover_img": "blahblah",
    "rating": "10/10"
}
```

How can I merge these two data sets together into one model that can be easily loaded via a collection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a good practice to keep a separation of concerns.
So, I would recommend doing the following:

1. MoviesCollection => should be a collection of MovieModel. It should only load the movies array from the source url.
2. the MovieModel should make the fetch to fetch its additional data.
   You can add a listener in the model's initialize function which will trigger the "fetch" method.

The model of the movie is responsible for fetching
additional data:

```
var Movie = Backbone.Model.extend({
    url: function() {
        return 'http://movieapi.com/movie/' + this.movieid;
    },

    initialize: function(){
        this.fetch();
    }
});
```

The collection of movies is resposible for fetching a list of movies with its id:

```
var Movies = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Movie,

    url: 'http://movieapi/popular',

    // need to intercept the response since the array of movies
    // is nested inside the response
    parse: function(res) {
        if (res && res.movies) {
            return res.movies;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: How would I make sure that the Movie model had loaded its "extra data" before it was rendered in a view?

Comment: There is two cases:

1. Data doesn't block rendering.

  You can render data that you have as soon as possible and rerender with additional data when model will be fetched.

2. Data blocks rendering.

  In this case you can use `$.when` and fact that `fetch` returns a promise. You can just write something like:
  `$.when.apply($, movies.map(function(movie){ return movie.fetch(); })).then(/* do some rendering */)`

Comment: hi @jduncanator, I can suggest 2 possibilities:
1. Register a listener inside the Movie model to a certain property coming from the extra data, i.e: this.on("change:full-description", this.onExtraDataChange, this); and then on the callback function, trigger a custom event that will notify that the model's data is ready: i.e. this.trigger('ready:movie').
2. On the other hand, you can put the same logic on the view that renders the model, and render the model's data when the extra property has changed.